# Laravel React API returns 404(Not Found) when sending axios post request even though the route is present in api.php

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I keep getting 404 error when I try to submit the form even though the routes are correctly placed in api.php.Can somebody please help??

```
const url = "/api/add-feedback";
const token = process.env.MIX_REACT_APP_API_TOKEN;
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [review, setReview] = useState("");

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        review: review
    }

    const res = await axios.post(url, data, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        },
    });
    if (res.data.status === 200) {
        console.log(res.data.message);
    }
}
```

Here is the route in api.php

```
Route::post('/add-feedback',[ApiController::class,'feedback']);
```

Here is the ApiController function

```
 public function feedback(Request $res)
{
    $data = $res->validate([
        'name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'review'=>'required'
    ]);
    Feedback::create($data);
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 200,
        'message' => 'Feedback Added Successfully'
    ]);
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
app.js:3415 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add-feedback 404 (Not Found)
app.js:3880 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

Comment: Why you're using `const token = process.env.MIX_REACT_APP_API_TOKEN;` ?

Comment: It's used for API Authentication.

Comment: Why not use Login to create auth tokens and add it inside a group middleware auth to properly get the response ?

Comment: Even if I remove the auth token, problem doesn't get solved.

Comment: Posted an answer for you please check.

Answer (score 0):

The error is you're using promises with axios, modify your code to something like this:

```
axios.post(url, data,{
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    },
})
.then((response) => {
  if (res.data.status === 200) {
    console.log(res.data.message);
  }
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

This will send a post request to your route with the data specified.